# Invalid use of property. How to loop through collection that belongs to an object?

Tags: vba, excel

I am a complete beginner at Excel VBA and I am trying to organize some data I have by using custom classes.  I have looked through many examples, but I am having trouble finding good examples of exactly what I am trying to do.

My data consists of a list of parts, quantities, and manufacturing operations to be performed on them.  In my custom class which I named "MOPart", each part has one property for its name and quantity, but it has a property collection for each process it undergoes.

In the spreadsheet I have, there is a new line for each manufacturing process, so there will be a duplicate entry for that part name and quantity.  What I am trying to do is loop through each line, detect if there is already an object that matches that part name;  if not, create a new MOPart object, but if there is, add the name of the manufacturing process on that line to the collection property for the existing object.

An example of what I would like as properties of an object:

```
part.name = ABC123
part.qty = 12
part.routings(1) = Laser
part.routings(2) = Machining
part.routings(3) = Weld
```

Below is code that I have so far.  My class module, MOPart:

```
Option Explicit

Private pQty As Integer
Private pRoutings As Collection
Private pname As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pRoutings = New Collection
End Sub

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pname
End Property
Property Let Name(vname As String)
    pname = vname
End Property

Property Get qty() As Integer
    qty = pQty
End Property
Property Let qty(vqty As Integer)
    pQty = vqty
End Property

Property Set Routings(c As Collection)
    Set pRoutings = c
End Property

Property Get Routing(v As Integer) As String
    Routing = pRoutings(v)
End Property
```

And my module to test this out:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mps As Collection

Sub TestMod()
    Dim partexist As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rtg As String
    Dim mp As MOPart
    Dim crtg As Collection

Set mps = New Collection

' test first few entries in the data set
For i = 2 To 10
    partexist = False
    Set mp = New MOPart

    ' for each entry beisdes the first
    If mps.count > 0 Then

        ' loop through collection to find if there is an entry already
        For Each mp In mps

            ' if the part already exists
            If mp.Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                partexist = True            'set flag that part exists
                crtg.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value  ' add new routing
                Set mp.Routings = crtg
            End If
        Next mp
    End If

    ' if part name not found in list of parts
    If Not partexist Then

        ' Set properties for new part
        With mp
            .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
            .qty = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
        End With

        Set crtg = New Collection  ' new collection representing routings for new part
        crtg.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
        Set mp.Routings = crtg

        ' add to collection of parts
        mps.Add mp

    End If

Next i



' after objects are all created, loop thru each routing of each part
For Each mp In mps
    For i = 1 To mp.Routings.count     ' COMPILER ERROR HERE: invalid use of property
' Also tried this line as for each rtg in mp.Routings
        MsgBox (mp.Name & "    " & mp.qty & "    " & mp.Routing(i))
    Next i
Next mp

End Sub
```

The compiler doesn't seem to like when I use mp.Routings.  I am sure it is some simple syntax error I am overlooking, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice is appreciated; perhaps there is a cleaner way to do what I am doing, which I am open to hear as well.

Thanks in advance.

edit 1: Thanks to Ron's comment below for advising me to add a "add" method to the custom class.  I added an add method as follows:

```
Public Sub add(rtg As String)
    pRoutings.add rtg
End Sub
```

I also added a CountRoutings method, that would return a the number of routings:

```
Public Function CountRoutings() As Integer
    CountRoutings = pRoutings.count
End Function
```

In my test module, I changed `For i = 1 to mp.Routings.Count` to For `i = 1 to mp.CountRoutings`

However, I still don't understand why I can't use mp.Routings.count.  Do I need a separate class module for routings or something?  Or do I need a "property get" for routings?

Comment: `Routings` is a collection so you should use `Add` to create new items.  `Routings(n)` is to access items that have already been created.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Is this syntax incorrect for adding to routings?
                `code` crtg.Add ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value  ' add new routing  Set mp.Routings = crtg

Comment: You need an `Add` method in your custom class.  Then, in the regular module, you would do something like `mp.add`.  Also, instead of looping, you can test for `exists` by testing for `Error 457` when trying to do an `Add` to the mps collection.  And if mp has already been added to the mps collection; then `mps(key).add` "routing"

Comment: I do not like VBA classes. There are many who swear by them but if I have a problem complicated enough to need classes, I switch to another language.  Have you tried a VBA user type which is what other languages call a structure. You cannot associate code with a structure so you cannot hide functionality or have private routines as you can with a class but they are much easier to use.  P.S.  Please use `Long` instead of `Integer`.  `Integer` declares a 16-bit variable which requires special processing on 16 and 32-bit computers.

Answer (score 0):

ClassModule: MOPart

```
Option Explicit

Private pQty As Long
Private pRoutings As Collection
Private pname As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pRoutings = New Collection
End Sub

Property Get Name() As String           '--------------------------------------
    Name = pname
End Property
Property Let Name(vname As String)
    pname = vname
End Property

Property Get Qty() As Long              '--------------------------------------
    Qty = pQty
End Property
Property Let Qty(vqty As Long)
    pQty = vqty
End Property

Property Set Routings(c As Collection)  '--------------------------------------
    Set pRoutings = c
End Property
Property Get Routings() As Collection
    Set Routings = pRoutings
End Property

Public Function getRouting(ByVal v As Long) As String
    getRouting = pRoutings(v)
End Function
```

---

.

Test Module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mps As Collection

Public Sub test()
    setObjects
    testObjects
End Sub

Public Sub setObjects()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, mp As MOPart, rtg As Collection
    Set mps = New Collection
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 2 To 4
            Set mp = New MOPart
            mp.Name = .Cells(i, 1).Value2:  mp.Qty = .Cells(i, 4).Value2
            Set rtg = New Collection
            For j = 2 To 4
                rtg.Add .Cells(j, 7).Value2
            Next
            Set mp.Routings = rtg:  mps.Add mp
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub testObjects()
    Dim i As Long, mp As MOPart, msg As String
    For Each mp In mps
        With mp
            msg = msg & "part.name: " & vbTab & mp.Name & vbCrLf
            msg = msg & "part.qty: " & vbTab & vbTab & mp.Qty & vbCrLf
            For i = 1 To mp.Routings.Count
                msg = msg & "part.routings(" & i & "):" & vbTab & mp.getRouting(i) & vbCrLf
            Next: msg = msg & vbCrLf
        End With
    Next: MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

---

Test file:

[image: Test file]

---

Result:

[image: Result]

---

Some of the issues in the posted code:

- "Set Routings()" and "Get Routing()" (missing "s")
- A Get property must have 1 less parameter than Set
- The mps collection would not get populated because of `If mps.count > 0` after initialization